# Can I use c# exe in a fashion similar to PHP in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, c#, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently using jquery to send data from javascript to a php file to execute some server side code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'myfile.php', //instead of php, can I call a exe (c#) or asp page here?
        type: "POST",
        data: ({name: Dummy}),
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

I am facing issues in passing values from my javascript to php file, data is dropped at adfs (eso). So I want to know if a c# exe, or an asp page can be called instead of a php and is it advisable, are there any other way of passing values from client end to server side, my website is made of html files and javascript only.

tried passing this aspx page as URL in above code

```
Url ="mydomain.com/site/default.aspx";
```

on the aspx page I am reading

```
string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
```

but the aspx page isnt getting executed (like a php does otherwise)

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I added the code that I tried - using aspx -  but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), ASP.Net have something know as WebAPI which is great for HTTP services and potentially perfect for what you want.

EDIT:

Based on a comment here is a really basic controller with Get and Post verbs

```
    public class DummiesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet()]
        [Route("api/dummies")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return this.Ok(new[] {new Dummy(), new Dummy()});
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        [Route("api/dummies/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
        {
            return this.Ok(new Dummy());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/dummies")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(Dummy dummy)
        {
            int id = 1;
            return this.Created($"api/dummies/{id}", dummy);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This link only shows get operations, can it be used for post operations and called using javascript?

Comment: When you create the controller there is an option to include read and write actions. This will add examples for GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.